# Cannot execute shell command from Electron packaged app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I have my Electron app which I am packaging with `electron-packager` npm module. 
I want to execute an python application only by name from Nodejs module called *child_process*. When the application isn't packaged it works, but when I package it does not work. I noticed that the packaged app does not load **PATH** variable so it works only if I change it to absolute path to the script. But I want to make it platform independent, so it is not a solution for me.

Is there any way how can I "inject" **PATH** variable to the packaged application or any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably [this PATH issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7688).

And you can fix it with [this package](https://github.com/sindresorhus/fix-path).

```
const fixPath = require('fix-path');

fixPath();

console.log(process.env.PATH);
//=> '/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `spawn` to spin off your child process? If so, that is launched without a shell, therefore no `PATH`. However, you can force it to use a shell.

`const myCmd = spawn('ls', args, { shell: true });`

Alternatively, you could use `exec` which does run with a shell. [Here's an article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) that goes into depth on the differences.